# How to show/hide more than 1000 markers with good perfomance?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

What approach, solution can I use to show more than one thousand of markers over the map with good perfomance?

Comment: from the [documentation (Too Many Markers!)](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers)

Answer (score 0):

i have a project based on this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

my map shows up to 3000 markers for each query and it works good